# Calculate amount of iterations

Tags: loops, complexity-theory

How can I calculate how many iterations will be done by these loops for any given N (>= 1)

```
for (1 <= k <= N)
    for (0 <= i < 6)
        for (0 <= j < k)
            ...
```

I'm especially having problems of how to deal with the innermost loop, because it depends on the value of the outermost loop. Basicall, it will be something like `N * 6 * ???`, but I can't figure out what `???` should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`???` should be (N+1)/2, the sum on positive integers up to N.  Just to make sure I wrote a powershell script to check that theory:

```
for($N=1; $N -le 10; $N++)
{
  $totalCount = 0

  for ($k=1; $k -le $N; $k++)
  {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt 6; $i++)
    {
      for ($j=0; $j -lt $k; $j++)
      {    
        $totalCount++
      }
    }
  }

  Write-Host("Total Count for N={0} is {1}" -f $N, $totalCount)
  $calcTotal = ($N*($N+1)/2)*6
  Write-Host("Calulated total ={0}" -f $calcTotal)
}
```

Which yields:

```
Total Count for N=1 is 6
Calulated total =6
Total Count for N=2 is 18
Calulated total =18
Total Count for N=3 is 36
Calulated total =36
Total Count for N=4 is 60
Calulated total =60
Total Count for N=5 is 90
Calulated total =90
Total Count for N=6 is 126
Calulated total =126
Total Count for N=7 is 168
Calulated total =168
Total Count for N=8 is 216
Calulated total =216
Total Count for N=9 is 270
Calulated total =270
Total Count for N=10 is 330
Calulated total =330
```

Answer (score 2):

Without changing how many times the internal loop is executed (though you will change the order), you can change the loops to: (this can be done since `i` and `j` are independent of each other)

```
for (1 <= k <= N)
  for (0 <= j < k)
    for (0 <= i < 6)
```

Ignoring `i` for the moment, we have:

```
k             1  2    3     ... N
j             0  0 1  0 1 2     0 1 2 ... N-1
              -  ---  -----     -------------
executions    1   2     3             N
```

That is, `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N+1)/2` executions (that's [a well-known formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) worth knowing for these types of calculations).

Adding `i` simply increases this by a factor of 6, so we have `3*N(N+1)`.

Comment: Seems correct, but N = 1 will result in 0 iterations following your formula, when it actuall loops 6 times (which is easy to follow)